# VBA Collecting data from various files -> files cannot be found within folder

Tags: excel, vba, aggregate

I need to collect data from various Excel files and aggregate them within one "master file". With the code provided below, I was able to do that as I wanted to. This masterfile is in an other folder than the files I am trying to collect and aggregate.
However, having saved the code, closed the excel file and reopened it to check if it's working a second time, an error occurs.
That error states that a certain file cannot be found and the code stops immediately.
I wonder how it's possible that everything was pretty fine and at the second try it doesn't work at all.

The line of code which is problematic is this one: "With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=QuellDateiAktuell$)"

Second question - that's solely nice to have, so no need to work on that additionaly, if you do not have a solution anyways - is there a possibility to name the sheets in the excel file according to the last 15 digits of the files where the data comes from respectively?

So many thanks in advance, I am pretty desperate!

```
        ''' 
        Sub Collect Data ()
        Dim Folder$             ('this is where the aggregated data should be visible)
        Dim QuellDateien$, QuellDateiAktuell$ ('first one the folder where the data is at the moment; 
                                                the second one, each file with data within this current folder)
        Dim wbkZiel As Workbook

        With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        End With
        
        Folder$ = "W:\...\test.xlsm"
        QuellDateien$ = "W:\(every file in this last folder with the following ending:)\*.xlsb"
        
        'Open folder and open the first file from where the data should be collected
        Set wbkZiel = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folder$)
        QuellDateiAktuell$ = Dir(PathName:=QuellDateien$)

        'Loop to check, if there are other files
        Do Until Len (QuellDateiAktuell$) = 0

        'Open the files, copy Sheet1 and close the file
        
        '......AN ERROR OCCURS IN THE FOLLOWING, NAMELY "File cannot be found! ALTOUGH THERE IS A                         
         FILE ACTUALLY"......

        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=QuellDateiAktuell$)
        .Sheets(1).Copy After:=wbkZiel.Sheets(1)
        .Close savechanges:=False
        End With

        'get the next folder and so on
        QuellDateiAktuell$ = Dir ()

        Loop

        With Application
        .ScreenUpdation = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        End With

        End Sub
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dir returns just the file name and extension. You need to re-attach the directory path in order to open the file.

```vb
Function FileOpen(ByVal Directory As String, ByVal Name_Format As String) As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Dir(Directory & Name_Format)
    Set FileOpen = Application.Workbooks.Open(Directory & FileName) '<- I add the directory again
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Frankly, it didn't help me because I am simply too unversed in VBA. I found another code which worked. Nevertheless thank you for your effort!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found something that worked! I would appreciate it if you could give me the check mark on my answer.